# How map Key/Value pairs between two separate RDDs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, string-matching

Still a beginner in Scala and Spark, I think I'm just being brainless here. I have two RDDs, one of the type :-

```
((String, String), Int) = ((" v67430612_serv78i"," fb_201906266952256"),1)
```

Other of the type :-

```
(String, String, String) = (r316079113_serv60i,fb_100007609418328,-795000)
```

As it can be seen, the first two columns of the two RDDs are of the same format. Basically they are ID's, one is 'tid' and the other is 'uid'.

The question is this :

Is there a method by which I can compare the two RDDs in such a manner that the tid and uid are matched in both and all the data for the same matching ids is displayed in a single row without any repetitions?

Eg : If I get a match of tid and uid between the two RDDs

```
((String, String), Int) = ((" v67430612_serv78i"," fb_201906266952256"),1)

(String, String, String) = (" v67430612_serv78i"," fb_201906266952256",-795000)
```

Then the output is:-

```
((" v67430612_serv78i"," fb_201906266952256",-795000),1)
```

The IDs in the two RDDs are not in any fixed order. They are random i.e the same uid and tid serial number may not correspond in  both the RDDs.

Also, how will the solution change if the first RDD type stays the same but the second RDD changes to type :-

```
((String, String, String), Int) = ((daily_reward_android_5.76,fb_193055751144610,81000),1)
```

I have to do this without the use of Spark SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to convert your `rdds` to `dataframes` and apply `join` for easiness.

Your first `dataframe` should be

```
+------------------+-------------------+-----+
|tid               |uid                |count|
+------------------+-------------------+-----+
| v67430612_serv78i| fb_201906266952256|1    |
+------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

The second `dataframe` should be

```
+------------------+-------------------+-------+
|tid               |uid                |amount |
+------------------+-------------------+-------+
| v67430612_serv78i| fb_201906266952256|-795000|
+------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

Then getting the final output is just `inner` `join` as

```
df2.join(df1, Seq("tid", "uid"))
```

which will give output as

```
+------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
|tid               |uid                |amount |count|
+------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
| v67430612_serv78i| fb_201906266952256|-795000|1    |
+------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
```

**Edited**

If you want to do it without dataframe/spark sql then there is join in rdd way too but you will have to modify as below

```
rdd2.map(x => ((x._1, x._2), x._3)).join(rdd1).map(y => ((y._1._1, y._1._2, y._2._1), y._2._2))
```

This will work only if you have `rdd1` and `rdd2` as defined in your question as `((" v67430612_serv78i"," fb_201906266952256"),1)` and `(" v67430612_serv78i"," fb_201906266952256",-795000)` respectively.
you should have final output as

```
(( v67430612_serv78i, fb_201906266952256,-795000),1)
```

Make sure that you trim the values for empty spaces. This will help you to be sure that both rdds have same values for key while joining, otherwise you might get an empty result.

Comment: Why acceptance? you wanted help without spark SQL, isn't it?

Comment: No offence! Officially yes. But unofficially this also teaches me something new since I have never worked in SQL alone or with Spark before. That's why the acceptance and upvote.

Comment: I think you can use RDD map, mapPartitions and join method to achieve your goal.

Comment: @QueepyDev people will stop looking into your question since you already accepted answer for this question. I agree  that you can do upvote as it is useful to you.

Comment: But the RDD types are different. Won't that result in a type mismatch?? @Tom

Comment: Removed the accpetance! I didn't know that  @Arvind Kumar Anugula

Comment: @ Ramesh Maharjan. Two questions :- 1. Will this work if the entries don't correspond in the two RDDs i.e the first entry uid and tid of RDD 1 are not the same as the first entry uid and tid of RDD 2? 2. On executing the solution, I got the error "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection" which led me to asking the first question.

Comment: Make sure that your rdds are not empty. Yes it will work for different uid and tid. For your second question, either you need to ask another question in stackoverflow or you need to update your question.

Comment: @ Ramesh Maharjan I checked carefully. Both the RDDs I'm passing in the solution are not empty, they are returning values. Yet, when I execute the solution, I get  "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection". Why??

Comment: update your question please. with some rdds of your data

Comment: @ Ramesh Maharjan Posted a fresh question with all  the details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880551/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-empty-collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148196/discussion-between-ramesh-maharjan-and-queepydev).