# "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection"

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I'm working with Spark 2.1.1 and Scala 2.11.8

I'm executing my code in Spark-shell. This is the code I'm executing

```
val read_file1 = sc.textFile("Path to file 1");

val uid = read_file1.map(line => line.split(",")).map(array => array.map(arr => {
 | if(arr.contains(":")) (array(2).split(":")(0), arr.split(":")(0))
 |  else (array(2).split(":")(0), arr)}))

val rdd1 = uid.map(array => array.drop(4)).flatMap(array => array.toSeq).map(y=>(y,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

My output of this code is :

```
(( v67430612_serv78i, fb_201906266952256),1)
(( v74005958_serv35i, fb_128431994336303),1)
```

However for the two RDDs' outputs, when I execute :

```
uid2.map(x => ((x._1, x._2), x._3)).join(rdd1).map(y => ((y._1._1, y._1._2, y._2._1), y._2._2))
```

I get the error :

```
 "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection"
```

Why am I getting this error?

Here are samples of the input files:-

File 1 :

```
2017-05-09 21:52:42 , 1494391962 , p69465323_serv80i:10:450 , 7 , fb_406423006398063:396560, guest_861067032060185_android:671051, fb_100000829486587:186589, fb_100007900293502:407374, fb_172395756592775:649795
2017-05-09 21:52:42 , 1494391962 , z67265107_serv77i:4:45 , 2:Re , fb_106996523208498:110066, fb_274049626104849:86632, fb_111857069377742:69348, fb_127277511127344:46246
```

File 2 :

```
fb_100008724660685,302502,-450,v300430479_serv73i:10:450,switchtable,2017-04-30 00:00:00    
fb_190306964768414,147785,-6580,r308423810_serv31i::20,invite,2017-04-30 00:00:00
```

I just noted this : When I'm executing

```
rdd1.take(10).foreach(println) or rdd1.first()
```

I get this message too before the output :

```
WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 39979424 bytes, TID = 11
```

I don't know if this might have anything to do with the problem??

Another note : this error only occurs when I do

```
res.first()
```

for

```
uid2.map(x => ((x._1, x._2), x._3)).join(rdd1).map(y => ((y._1._1, y._1._2, y._2._1), y._2._2))
```

On doing

```
res.take(10).foreach(println)
```

I don't get any output but no error is returned either.

Comment: Can you share the whole exception stack trace?

Comment: @ stefanobaghino I don't have the whole stacktrace. I get the ...48 elided message. Please let me know how to get the whole thing

Comment: So you only get a single line that says `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection`?

Comment: @ stefanobaghino  I get this : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1370)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1367)
  ... 48 elided

Comment: if you have a csv file why dont you use spark-csv file to read the files ?

Comment: I actually did not know it made a difference. Till now I had read csv files as sc.textFile without any problems so I did the same here.

Comment: Furthermore, what is `res`?

Comment: res is the return variable you get in Spark-Shell (res0, res1, res2......)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `trim` the *spaces* in the tuples created from splitted line so nothing was joined as they didn't match. So when you tried `take` from an empty `rdd`, exception was thrown.

You can use following solution. Its working in mine.

```
val read_file1 = sc.textFile("Path to file 1");

val uid = read_file1.map(line => line.split(",")).map(array => array.map(arr => {
   if(arr.contains(":")) (array(2).split(":")(0).trim, arr.split(":")(0).trim)
    else (array(2).split(":")(0).trim, arr.trim)}))

val rdd1 = uid.map(array => array.drop(4)).flatMap(array => array.toSeq).map(y=>(y,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)


val read_file2 = sc.textFile("Path to File 2");
val uid2 = read_file2.map(line => {var arr = line.split(","); (arr(3).split(":")(0).trim,arr(0).trim,arr(2).trim)});

val res = uid2.map(x => ((x._1, x._2), x._3)).join(rdd1).map(y => ((y._1._1, y._1._2, y._2._1), y._2._2))
res.take(10).foreach(println)
```

Comment: @ Ramesh Maharjan Can the size of the file have something to do with this?? Because the problem is still there :(

Comment: here's a link of the screenshot for this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_VulQELUNoFNlh6dG5QUFY1VWs

Answer (score 1):

You get an empty collection after the `join`, it happens when there are now corresponding keys in rdds. Either keys are not trimmed, sliced incorrectly or there were not any matches at all. I suggest checking if there are matching keys in your files/rdds, checking if the data was extracted correctly and checking if you need `inner join` rather than `left` or `right outer join`.